# Firefox 3.6.13 configuration for spnego authentification

Tags: firefox3.6, spnego

I'd like to access to a web application which requires spnego authentification.
This application is running on a network on which i'm connected by VPN connection. Proxy not used.

It works fine under IE6/7/8, Chrome but not firefox 3.6.13

The matter on firefox is: I don't have the prompt message box to enter username and password

To configure my FF, i applied the [following instructions](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/beta/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/info/aes/ae/tsec_SPNEGO_config_web.html), adding the domain name to the trusted and delegation uris fields.

Trying to access to the application, i get the following error message:

> A browser did not respond to authentication challenge sent by a server.
>   Most probably your browser is not configured properly to handle SPNEGO authentication challenge or does not support SPNEGO.
>   Please, contact your System Administrator to deal with the problem.

Using TCPMon to get an overview of the informations received:

```
GET /AppName HTTP/1.1
Host: app.domain:8182
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; fr; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203     Firefox/3.6.13 ( .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET4.0E)
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: fr,fr-fr;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 115
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: JSESSIONID=6E058E24D9E1873C80B14C56EC59B1E4

GET /AppName/ HTTP/1.1
Host: app.domain:8182
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; fr; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203     Firefox/3.6.13 ( .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET4.0E)
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: fr,fr-fr;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 115
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: JSESSIONID=6E058E24D9E1873C80B14C56EC59B1E4

GET /AppName/logon HTTP/1.1
Host: app.domain:8182
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; fr; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203     Firefox/3.6.13 ( .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET4.0E)
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: fr,fr-fr;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 115
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: JSESSIONID=6E058E24D9E1873C80B14C56EC59B1E4
```

---

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Déplacé Temporairement
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Location: http://app.domain:8182/AppName/
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Tue, 14 Dec 2010 16:16:28 GMT

0

HTTP/1.1 302 Déplacé Temporairement
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Powered-By: Servlet 2.4; JBoss-4.2.3.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_4_2_3_GA             date=200807181417)/JBossWeb-2.0
Location: http://app.domain:8182/AppName/logon
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 0
Date: Tue, 14 Dec 2010 16:16:28 GMT

HTTP/1.1 401 Non-Autorisé
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Pragma: No-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 01:00:00 CET
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Tue, 14 Dec 2010 16:16:28 GMT

4b9
```

I've checked for the other browsers and i got the same informations.

Do someone have an idea why FF can't interprete it, prompt a dialog box or enter the application ?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Best regards.

Comment: Debugging Mozilla firefox sources while trying to acces to my application, FF goes in error with the following code: LOGON DENIED. Credentials still not prompted.

Comment: Not working since i changed my user password. Maybe FF has saved my username and password somewhere, doesn't ask them and send it to the server which reject the authentification ?